# Simple word scrambler

Tags: python-3.x

```
counter = 0
sentence = 'Hello World'
split = str.split(sentence)

for str in split:
  c = split[counter]
  scramble = c[4] + c[0] + c[3] + c[1] + c[2]
  counter += 1
  print (scramble)
```

The program should rearrange each word in a string into a specific pattern but I cannot figure out how to print the scrambled text onto the same line.

Comment: `c = split[counter]`   is your issue.  `split` is already a string, so you're taking the first letter of that string instead of the entire word and trying to scramble it.

Comment: Your use of `counter` seems a bit silly since you're not using the `str` variable your loop gives you. Speaking of it, you shouldn't use `str` as the name of your own variable, since it's already the name of a builtin type (which you'll shadow if you use it yourself). It sounds like you may want `for word in split: print(word[4] + word[0] + word[3] + word[1] + word[2], end="")`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
counter = 0
sentence = 'Hello World'
split = str.split(sentence)

for str in split:
  c = split[counter]
  scramble = c[4] + c[0] + c[3] + c[1] + c[2]
  counter += 1
  print (scramble, end=" ")
```

The print function accepts an `end` parameter which defaults to "\n". Setting it to an empty string prevents it from issuing a new line at the end of the line.

Comment: If this was a correct answer, pleas mark it up. Thanks.